# Lambda Function not executing after batch implementation, but not showing any error

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, concurrent.futures

I have a function to insert my .xlslx file rows into DDB. everything was working fine and with the 15min time out and 128MB memory I could do it perfectly. Now for a very specific file I have 160K rows to be inserted, so I've increased memory to 1024MB and tried to implement batch requests. Nothing else changed (all triggers, authorisations, etcc... are up and running). But now the function is not even triggered. Not even CloudWatch logs are appearing.

```
import os
import boto3
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

# Configure logger
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# AWS service clients
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')

# Define your S3 bucket name and DynamoDB table name
# BUCKET_NAME = 'sellersinternal'
TABLE_NAME = 'Seller'

# Define the mapping of file names to column mappings
# Add more mappings as needed for other files (this one is based on marketPlaces Scraping)
file_column_mappings = {
    'sellers_testing.xlsx': {
        'Seller Name': ['SellerName'],
        'Listing URL': ['SellerUrl'],
        'Headquarter': ['SellerHq'],
        'Revenue': ['SellerRevenue'],
        'Year Founded': ['SellerYear'],
        'Number of Employees': ['SellerEmployeeCount'],
        'Icon URL': ['SellerOriginalIconUrl'],  # New column
        'Category L2': ['SellerCategory'],
        'Category L3': ['SellerSubCategory']
    }
}

def batch_write_items(table_name, items):
    dynamodb.batch_write_item(RequestItems={table_name: items})

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info("Starting Lambda function execution...")

    # Get the uploaded file from the S3 event
    file_obj = event['Records'][0]
    bucket_name = file_obj['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_key = file_obj['s3']['object']['key']

    # Get the appropriate column mapping based on the file name
    column_mapping = file_column_mappings.get(os.path.basename(file_key), None)

    try:
        # Read the XLSX file from S3
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_key)
        excel_data = response['Body'].read()

        # Parse the XLSX file using Pandas
        excel_df = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(excel_data))

        # Capture the S3 bucket upload time
        s3_upload_time = file_obj['eventTime']

        # Initialize a list to store items for batch processing
        batch_items = []

        # Iterate through each row and prepare items for insertion
        for _, row in excel_df.iterrows():
            item = {
                'SellerTimestamp': {'S': str(datetime.now())}
            }

            for excel_column, dynamodb_attributes in column_mapping.items():
                for dynamodb_attribute in dynamodb_attributes:
                    if dynamodb_attribute not in item:
                        item[dynamodb_attribute] = {'S': str(row[excel_column])}
                    else:
                        if not isinstance(item[dynamodb_attribute], list):
                            item[dynamodb_attribute] = [item[dynamodb_attribute]]
                        item[dynamodb_attribute].append({'S': str(row[excel_column])})

                if 'SellerName' in item:
                    item['SellerNameLC'] = {'S': item['SellerName']['S'].lower()}
                    seller_name = item.get('SellerName', {}).get('S', '')
                    seller_name_lc = ''.join(seller_name.split()).lower()  # Remove spaces and make lowercase
                    item['SellerId'] = {'S': seller_name_lc}

            # Append the item to the batch_items list
            batch_items.append({'PutRequest': {'Item': item}})

            # If batch_items reaches the batch size (25), start a batch write request in parallel
            if len(batch_items) == 25:
                with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=15) as executor:
                    futures = [executor.submit(batch_write_items, TABLE_NAME, batch_items)]
                batch_items = []

        # Perform a final batch write request for any remaining items
        if batch_items:
            batch_write_items(TABLE_NAME, batch_items)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error: %s", e)
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': 'Error: ' + str(e)
        }
```

Comment: How are you calling the lambda?

Comment: Hi, sorry to not reply back before. The trigger (S3 upload) was added, but for some reason wasnt working, was solved by removing and adding back again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just and update. The trigger (S3 upload) was added and appearing for me, but for some reaons wasn't working. I've amanged to solve it by removing it and adding back again.